# Скрипт неправильно сортирует файлы по расширению в словаре

Tags: python-3.x

Всем доброго дня у меня возник такой проблема скрипт неправильно сортирует файлы по расширению в словаре

```
{'bates': ['/home/i92/game/test1.bates'],
'test': ['/home/i92/game/test1.bates']}
```

А должно быть

```
{'bates': ['/home/i92/game/test1.bates'],
 'test': ['/home/i92/game/test1.test']}
```

вот код

```
import os, fnmatch, pprint

def func(dp,*pat):
  lis=list()
  for x in list(pat):        
     (shortname, exctension)=os.path.splitext(x)
     ex=exctension.strip('.')
     lis.append(ex)

  l=list()
  for r,d,f in os.walk(dp):
  for i in f:
     if fnmatch.fnmatch(i,x):
        l.append(os.path.join(r,i))


  d={k: [] for k in lis}
  for h in lis:
    for v in l:
      if h in v:
        d[h].append(v)

  pprint.pprint(d)

func("/home/i92/", "*.test", "*.bates")
```

Comment: Код нерабочий, поправьте отступы.

Comment: я в проправил отступ